# Subset igraph graph by label

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to subset a igraph graph by an edge characteristics (like its label). In the reproducible example I have shamelessly stolen from another post with a little modification, I would like to be able to separate the Best Friend ties (BF) from the Family ties (FAM):

```
edges <- matrix(c(103, 86, 24, 103, 103, 2, 92, 103, 87, 103, 103, 101, 103, 44), ncol=2, byrow=T)
g <- graph(as.vector(t(edges)))
E(g)[c(2:4,7)]$label<-"FAM"
E(g)[c(1,5,6)]$label<-"BF"
```

The best I can do so far is display the edges which have one type of tie:

```
E(g)[E(g)$label=="BF"]
V(g)[E(g)$label=="BF"]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

how about:

```
gfam <- subgraph.edges(graph=g, eids=which(E(g)$label=="FAM"), delete.vertices = TRUE)
gbf <- subgraph.edges(graph=g, eids=which(E(g)$label=="BF"), delete.vertices = TRUE)
```

Suggestion for igraph/network analysis tutorial/shameless plug:

https://solomonmg.github.io/post/working-with-bipartite-affiliation-network-data-in-r/

Stanford Network Analysis in R lab: [https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~brian/780/stanford%20social%20network%20labs/](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ebrian/780/stanford%20social%20network%20labs/)

Comment: link doesn't work anymore? Thanks!

Comment: Updated! Thanks

Answer (score 19):

I suggest you read `?V` and `?E` to see how to select edges and vertices. A quite compact and readable solution to your question is

```
subgraph.edges(g, E(g)[label=="FAM"])
subgraph.edges(g, E(g)[label=="BF"])
```

This removes the vertices as well, if they don't have an incident edge of the specified label. See `?subgraph.edges` for details.