# Subgraph an igraph to only include the top N "largest" nodes according to a specific attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I have a large graph in igraph, greater than 10,000 nodes.

```
> g
+ attr: size (v/n), value (v/n)
+ edges from... 
+ omitted several edges
```

I'd like to make a subgraph that contains only the nodes with the N largest `V(g)$size`s, where N is say 2000 so I can render it with fr in a reasonable amount of time (and `grid="nogrid"`).

I understand sampling graphs correctly is perilous, but I'm just looking to render a subgraph so that I can see what it looks like when I plot it.

What's the right subgraph syntax for this?

### Update

My minimalized data looks like this:

```
> df
   source target weight
1       1      2      1
2       1      3      1
3       1      4      1
4       2      4      2
5       3      4      3
6       4      8      3
7       5      8      3
8       6      8      3
9       7      9      3
10      8      9      5
11      9     10      5

> meta
   id skill
1   1    10
2   2     9
3   3    10
4   4     8
5   5     9
6   6     7
7   7     6
8   8     6
9   9     3
10 10     2
```

And

```
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=TRUE)
g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, 'skill', meta$id, meta$skill)
```

So my question is:

> How do I subset my graph by the nodes such that my subgraph contains
>   N=2 nodes with the largest value of V(g)$skill?

And this is what I have:

```
> N <- 2
> g2 <- subgraph(g, V(g)$skill >= tail(sort(V(g)$skill), n=N))
Warning message:
In subgraph(g, V(g)$skill >= tail(sort(V(g)$skill), n = N)) :
  At structural_properties.c:1984 :igraph_subgraph is deprecated from igraph 0.6, use igraph_induced_subgraph instead
> g2
IGRAPH 64e8069 DNW- 2 1 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), skill (v/n), weight (e/n)
+ edge from 64e8069 (vertex names):
[1] 1->3
>
```

It seems clumsy and like there is a built-in for this.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and what the expected output is. Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857718/subset-igraph-graph-by-label)?

Comment: Are you suggesting something like `subgraph.nodes(g, V(g)[size>....?])` and I don't understand what would go in the ...? in orderto argmax the size such that I only returned the N largest.

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example, perhaps we can work with something.

Comment: As far as I know there is not a built-in function. However, if you think about it, it is not more verbose than subsetting any other vector in base r. To avoid the warning use `induced_subgraph` instead of `subgraph`. If you are interested in more readable code you could try `tidygraph`: `g %>% as_tbl_graph() %>% top_n(2, skill)`.

Comment: I understand this is a matter of opinion, but that strikes me as clumsier and less readable than the subset command I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `induced_subgraph()` and `setdiff()` functions in order to split the original graph into two graphs `g1`, `g2`,

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(45)
n = 10
m = 20
g <- erdos.renyi.game(n=n, p.or.m=m, type="gnm", directed=TRUE)

V(g)$skill <- degree(g, mode = "in")
V(g)$name  <- LETTERS[1:n]

N = 2
N_set <- vector(,n)
split_rule = min(tail(sort(V(g)$skill), n=N))
N_set <- ifelse(V(g)$skill < split_rule, 0, 1)

###################################################################
# split into two graphs
# if (N_set[i]=1) then the node move to g1, else to g2 
###################################################################

vsubgraph <- c(1:length(N_set)) * N_set
vsubgraph <- vsubgraph[vsubgraph  != 0]

g1 <- induced_subgraph(g, vsubgraph)
g2 <- induced_subgraph(g, setdiff(V(g), vsubgraph))

V(g)[vsubgraph]$color <- "green"
V(g)[setdiff(V(g), vsubgraph)]$color <- "yellow"

V(g1)$name <- V(g)[vsubgraph]$name 
V(g2)$name <- V(g)[setdiff(V(g), vsubgraph)]$name

V(g1)$color <- "green"
V(g2)$color <- "yellow"

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
mylayout <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
mylayout1 <- matrix(setdiff(mylayout, mylayout[N_set == 0]), ncol=2)
mylayout2 <- matrix(setdiff(mylayout, mylayout[N_set != 0]), ncol=2)

plot(g, layout=mylayout,
          vertex.shape = "square",  
          vertex.label = V(g)$name,
          edge.arrow.size = 0.5, 
          main='Original graph'
     )

plot(g1, layout=mylayout1,
          vertex.shape = "square",  
          vertex.label = V(g1)$name,
          edge.arrow.size = 0.5, 
          main='1-st graph'
     )

plot(g2, layout=mylayout2,
          vertex.shape = "square",  
          vertex.label = V(g2)$name,
          edge.arrow.size = 0.5, 
          main='2-nd graph'
     )
```

The result in the figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try `induced_subgraph` like below

```
> N <- 3

> induced_subgraph(g,V(g)[V(g)$skill %in% tail(sort(V(g)$skill),N)])
IGRAPH de70765 DNW- 4 2 --
+ attr: name (v/c), skill (v/n), weight (e/n)
+ edges from de70765 (vertex names):
[1] 1->2 1->3
```