# plot a subset of igraph data , just subset by their attribute

Tags: r

I have a fblog data set ,PolParty is one attribute of my data, I want to plot just  2 political parties (say P1 and P2) and plot the network of blogs. 
i wrote code below but i think it is wrong , can some one help me?

```
library(statnet)
library(igraph)
library(sand)
data(fblog)
fblog = upgrade_graph(fblog)

class(fblog)
summary(fblog)
V(fblog)$PolParty
table(V(fblog)$PolParty)
p1<-V(fblog)[PolParty=="PS"] # by their labels/names
p2<-V(fblog)[PolParty=="UDF"]
class(p1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects `p1` and `p2` that you were creating are of the class `igraph.vs` (instead of `igraph`). This object just documents the vertices. Which is not a full graph. Hence when you try to plot it you don't get anything.
Based on the following post: [Subset igraph graph by label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857718/subset-igraph-graph-by-label)

```
g=subgraph.edges(graph=fblog, eids=which(V(fblog)$PolParty==" PS"), delete.vertices = TRUE)
plot(g)
```

The above works. NOTE: regarding the output of `V(fblog)$PolParty`- everything is preceeded by a space hence you need to use `V(fblog)$PolParty==" PS"`

UPDATE: if I want to subset based on 2 conditions- I will modify the `which()` command:

```
g=subgraph.edges(graph=fblog, eids=which(V(fblog)$PolParty==" PS"| V(fblog)$PolParty==" UDF"), delete.vertices = TRUE)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you , if I want to have 2 political parties lets say instead of just "PS", I want also "UDF", both together ,do you know how can I do this?   g=subgraph.edges(graph=fblog, eids=which(V(fblog)$PolParty==" PS"& V(fblog)$PolParty==" UDF"), delete.vertices = TRUE)

Comment: SORRY YOU KNOW HOW TO DO THIS?

Comment: Updated with a boolean term to say `equal to 'PS' OR 'UDF'`

Comment: can you help me to modify the code ?  I use table(V(g)$PolParty) , it gives me again all node also with other attribute, can you help me to modify the code ? because I just want NODES WHICH PolParty==" PS" and PolParty==" Les Verts".I dont know why

Comment: I GOT IT, THIS IS CORRECT: new_graph<-induced.subgraph(fblog,which(V(fblog)$PolParty %in% c(" PS"," UDF"))) 
new_graph                    
table(V(new_graph)$PolParty)